# Call and Callvirt

Tags: .net, reflection, cil, reflection.emit

What is the difference between the CIL instructions "Call" and "Callvirt"?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

`call` is for calling non-virtual, static, or superclass methods, i.e., the target of the call is not subject to overriding. `callvirt` is for calling virtual methods (so that if `this` is a subclass that overrides the method, the subclass version is called instead).

Comment: If I remember correctly `call` doesn't check the pointer against null before performing the call, something which `callvirt` obviously needs to. That is why `callvirt` sometimes is emitted by the compiler even though calling non-virtual methods.

Comment: Ah. Thanks for pointing that out (I'm not a .NET person). The analogies I use are call => invokespecial, and callvirt => invokevirtual, in JVM bytecode. In the case of the JVM, both instructions check "this" for nullness (I just wrote a test program to check).

Comment: You might want to mention the performance difference in your answer, that being the reason for having a 'call' instruction at all.

Comment: I disagree. Not having a performance difference would not eliminate the raison d'etre of the call (or invokespecial) instruction.

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young - You are wrong. Its **always** calvirt. Please read here - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericgu/archive/2008/07/02/why-does-c-always-use-callvirt.aspx

Comment: @AngshumanAgarwal Fair enough re C# always using `callvirt`. Regardless, my description of `call` and `callvirt` are (to my understanding) still correct, and my comment about how JVM bytecode works still holds---Java code that uses, say, `super.foobar()` would indeed still use `invokespecial` (and not `invokevirtual`).

Comment: The ```call``` instruction *is* actually emitted from time to time. From the ILDasm of a test C# program:
```IL_0021:  callvirt   instance void [ClassLibrary1]ClassLibrary1.Class1::sayHello()
IL_0026:  ldstr      "This was expected behavior. Will exit with code 100."
IL_002b:  *call*       void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(string)
IL_0030:  ldc.i4.s   100```

Answer (score 62):

When the runtime executes a `call` instruction it's making a call to an exact piece of code (method).  There's no question about where it exists.  <strike>Once the IL has been JITted, the resulting machine code at the call site is an unconditional `jmp` instruction.</strike>

By contrast, the `callvirt` instruction is used to call virtual methods in a polymorphic way.  The exact location of the method's code must be determined at runtime for each and every invocation.  The resulting JITted code involves some indirection through vtable structures.  Hence the call is slower to execute, but it is more flexible in that it allows for polymorphic calls.

Note that the compiler can emit `call` instructions for virtual methods.  For example:

```
sealed class SealedObject : object
{
   public override bool Equals(object o)
   {
      // ...
   }
}
```

Consider calling code:

```
SealedObject a = // ...
object b = // ...

bool equal = a.Equals(b);
```

While `System.Object.Equals(object)` is a virtual method, in this usage there is no way for an overload of the `Equals` method to exist.  `SealedObject` is a sealed class and cannot have subclasses.

For this reason, .NET's `sealed` classes can have better method dispatching performance than their non-sealed counterparts.

**EDIT:** Turns out I was wrong.  The C# compiler cannot make an unconditional jump to the method's location because the object's reference (the value of `this` within the method) might be null.  Instead it emits `callvirt` which does the null check and throws if required.

This actually explains some bizarre code I found in the .NET framework using Reflector:

```
if (this==null) // ...
```

It's possible for a compiler to emit verifiable code that has a null value for the `this` pointer (local0), only csc doesn't do this.

So I guess `call` is only used for class static methods and structs.

Given this information it now seems to me that `sealed` is only useful for API security.  I found [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2134/do-sealed-classes-really-offer-performance-benefits) that seems to suggest there are no performance benefits to sealing your classes.

**EDIT 2:** There's more to this than it seems.  For example the following code emits a `call` instruction:

```
new SealedObject().Equals("Rubber ducky");
```

Obviously in such a case there is no chance that the object instance could be null.

Interestingly, in a DEBUG build, the following code emits `callvirt`:

```
var o = new SealedObject();
o.Equals("Rubber ducky");
```

This is because you could set a breakpoint on the second line and modify the value of `o`.  In release builds I imagine the call would be a `call` rather than `callvirt`.

Unfortunately my PC is currently out of action, but I'll experiment with this once it's up again.

Comment: Sealed attributes are definitely faster when looking for them via reflection, but other than that, I don't know of any other benefits you haven't mentioned.

Answer (score 13):

> For this reason, .NET's sealed classes can have better method dispatching performance than their non-sealed counterparts.

Unfortunately this is not the case. Callvirt does one other thing that makes it useful. When an object has a method called on it callvirt will check if the object exists, and if not throws a NullReferenceException. Call will simply jump to the memory location even if the object reference is not there, and try to execute the bytes in that location.

What this means is that callvirt is always used by the C# compiler (not sure about VB) for classes, and call is always used for structs (because they can never be null or subclassed).

**Edit** In response to Drew Noakes comment: Yes it seems you can get the compiler to emit a call for any class, but only in the following very specific case:

```
public class SampleClass
{
    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (obj.ToString().Equals("Rubber Ducky", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            return true;

        return base.Equals(obj);
    }

    public void SomeOtherMethod()
    {
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // This will emit a callvirt to System.Object.Equals
        bool test1 = new SampleClass().Equals("Rubber Ducky");

        // This will emit a call to SampleClass.SomeOtherMethod
        new SampleClass().SomeOtherMethod();

        // This will emit a callvirt to System.Object.Equals
        SampleClass temp = new SampleClass();
        bool test2 = temp.Equals("Rubber Ducky");

        // This will emit a callvirt to SampleClass.SomeOtherMethod
        temp.SomeOtherMethod();
    }
}
```

**NOTE** The class does not have to be sealed for this to work.

So it looks like the compiler will emit a call if all these things are true:

- The method call is immediately after the object creation
- The method is not implemented in a base class

Comment: That makes sense.  I had studied CIL and made an assumption about the behaviour of the compiler.  Thanks for clearing this up.  I'll update my answer.

Comment: Actually I don't believe you're 100% correct here.  I've updated my post (edit 2).

Comment: Hi Cameron.  Can you clarify whether the analysis of this code was performed on a release build?

Comment: There's no difference between calls in the debug and release builds. The only difference is in the stack manipulation code between calls. CallVirt is used in the first call because it's not calling SampleClass.Equals but Object.Equals.

Comment: Just to point that the compiler will also emit `call` if the method is static.

Answer (score 8):

According to MSDN:

[Call](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.call.aspx):

The call instruction calls the method indicated by the method descriptor passed with the instruction. The method descriptor is a metadata token that indicates the method to call...The metadata token carries sufficient information to determine whether the call is to a static method, an instance method, a virtual method, or a global function. **In all of these cases the destination address is determined entirely from the method descriptor** (contrast this with the Callvirt instruction for calling virtual methods, where the destination address also depends upon the runtime type of the instance reference pushed before the Callvirt).

[CallVirt](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.callvirt.aspx):

The callvirt instruction calls a late-bound method on an object. That is, **the method is chosen based on the runtime type of obj rather than the compile-time class visible in the method pointer**. Callvirt can be used to call both virtual and instance methods.

So basically, different routes are taken to invoke an object's instance method, overriden or not:

Call: variable -> **variable's** type object -> method

CallVirt: variable -> object instance -> **object's** type object -> method

Answer (score 6):

One thing perhaps worth adding to the previous answers is,
there seems to be only one face to how "IL call" actually executes,
and two faces to how "IL callvirt" executes.

Take this sample setup.

```
    public class Test {
        public int Val;
        public Test(int val)
            { Val = val; }
        public string FInst () // note: this==null throws before this point
            { return this == null ? "NO VALUE" : "ACTUAL VALUE " + Val; }
        public virtual string FVirt ()
            { return "ALWAYS AN ACTUAL VALUE " + Val; }
    }
    public static class TestExt {
        public static string FExt (this Test pObj) // note: pObj==null passes
            { return pObj == null ? "NO VALUE" : "VALUE " + pObj.Val; }
    }
```

First, the CIL body of FInst() and FExt() is 100% identical, opcode-to-opcode
(except that one is declared "instance" and the other "static")
-- however, FInst() will get called with "callvirt" and FExt() with "call".

Second, FInst() and FVirt() will both be called with "callvirt"
-- even though one is virtual but the other isn't --
but it's not the "same callvirt" that will really get to execute.

Here's what roughly happens after JITting:

```
    pObj.FExt(); // IL:call
    mov         rcx, <pObj>
    call        (direct-ptr-to) <TestExt.FExt>

    pObj.FInst(); // IL:callvirt[instance]
    mov         rax, <pObj>
    cmp         byte ptr [rax],0
    mov         rcx, <pObj>
    call        (direct-ptr-to) <Test.FInst>

    pObj.FVirt(); // IL:callvirt[virtual]
    mov         rax, <pObj>
    mov         rax, qword ptr [rax]  
    mov         rax, qword ptr [rax + NNN]  
    mov         rcx, <pObj>
    call        qword ptr [rax + MMM]
```

The only difference between "call" and "callvirt[instance]" is that "callvirt[instance]" intentionally tries to access one byte from *pObj before it calls the direct pointer of the instance function (in order to possibly throw an exception "right there and then").

Thus, if you're annoyed by the number of times that you have to write the "checking part" of

```
var d = GetDForABC (a, b, c);
var e = d != null ? d.GetE() : ClassD.SOME_DEFAULT_E;
```

You cannot push "if (this==null) return SOME_DEFAULT_E;" down into ClassD.GetE() itself
(as the "IL callvirt[instance]" semantics prohibits you to do this)
but you're free to push it into .GetE() if you move .GetE() to an extension function somewhere (as the "IL call" semantic allows it -- but alas, losing access to private members etc.)

That said, the execution of "callvirt[instance]" has more in common
with "call" than with "callvirt[virtual]", since the latter may have to execute a triple indirection in order to find the address of your function.
(indirection to typedef base, then to base-vtab-or-some-interface, then to actual slot)

Hope this helps,
Boris

Answer (score 1):

Just adding to the above answers, I think the change has been made long back such that Callvirt IL instruction will get generated for all the instance methods and Call IL instruction will get generated for static methods.

Reference :

Pluralsight course "C# Language Internals - Part 1 by Bart De Smet (video -- Call instructions and call stacks in CLR IL in a Nutshell)

and also
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericgu/2008/07/02/why-does-c-always-use-callvirt/

Comment: `call` also gets used for base calls. Also, I believe that the roslyn compiler will generate `call` instructions for sealed/non-virtual methods if it can trivially determine that the object will never be null (eg. [calls generated from the null conditional operator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34535000/call-instead-of-callvirt-in-case-of-the-new-c-sharp-6-null-check)).