# Calling instance method on a null reference in IL

Tags: c#, null, cil

Is it correct that a instance method can be called on a null reference in IL..?
Is there any example to show this..?

Comment: Surely this isn't possible - what instance would you execute the method on?

Comment: @Adam: it is very possible with a bit of IL hackery. The code is still 100% verifiable, but the C# compiler would never emit such code.

Comment: Fair enough, how does it get from the null reference and redirect to the correct instance in memory?  For example, if the method modified internal state.

Comment: @Adam: Of course, this only works if the method doesn't access any of the object's fields as mentioned in Hans' and my answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, this is possible, as long as the method doesn't use `this` because the CLR does not do a null check for `call` instructions.

You would have to modify the IL by hand as the C# compiler would almost always generate a `callvirt` instruction<sup>1</sup>.

See this blog post for details and an example:

> **[Instance Methods Called on null References](https://web.archive.org/web/20100724141113/http://www.pvle.be:80/2010/07/instance-methods-called-on-null-references/)**

**Sample**

```
.method private hidebysig static void  Main(string[] args) cil managed
{
    .entrypoint
    // Code size       18 (0x12)
    .maxstack  1
    .locals init ([0] class SomeClass o, [1] string hello)
    IL_0000:  nop
    IL_0001:  ldnull
    IL_0002:  stloc.0
    IL_0003:  ldloc.0
    IL_0004:  call       instance string SomeClass::GetHello()
    IL_0009:  stloc.1
    IL_000a:  ldloc.1
    IL_000b:  call       void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(string)
    IL_0010:  nop
    IL_0011:  ret
}
```

<sup>1</sup>In fact the reason that the C# compiler emits `callvirt` even in cases where a simple `call` instruction would be sufficient is to prevent calling instance methods on null references. With this behavior of the compiler users will get a `NullReferenceException` so the weird situation of calling a method on a null pointer is avoided. Eric Gunnerson explained this in a blog post some time ago: ***[Why does C# always use callvirt?](https://web.archive.org/web/20160112223951/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericgu/archive/2008/07/02/why-does-c-always-use-callvirt.aspx)*** [Gishu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1695/gishu) also has a nice explanation in a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/845657/why-is-the-c-sharp-compiler-emitting-a-callvirt-instruction-for-a-gettype-meth/845721#845721).

Answer (score 5):

See my [blog entry](http://xacc.wordpress.com/2009/12/07/calling-an-instance-method-in-the-clr-without-an-instance/) for info.

IL code sample:

```
.class Program
{
  .method static void  Main(string[] args)
  {
    .entrypoint
    .locals init ([0] class Program p)
    ldloc.0 // but wait, it's still null!
    call   instance void Program::Awesome()
    ret
  } 

  .method instance void Awesome()
  {
    ldstr      "Awesome!"
    call       void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(string)
    ret
  } 

  .method public specialname rtspecialname instance void  .ctor()
  {
    ldarg.0
    call       instance void [mscorlib]System.Object::.ctor()
    ret
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The CLR doesn't require it, it is an implementation detail of the language.  C# and VB.NET perform the test.  C++/CLI is a notable managed language that permits it.  As long as the instance method doesn't reference any class members then nothing goes wrong.  If is does, NullReferenceException will be raised as normal, merely giving you a hard time finding out why.

```
#include "stdafx.h"

using namespace System;

ref class Test {
public:
    void Run() {
        Console::WriteLine("no problem");
    }
};

int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
    Test^ obj = nullptr;
    obj->Run();
    return 0;
}
```