# Performance of static properties/functions

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, vb.net, performance

is there a difference in performance when making properties static/shared that were instance properties before, maybe any locking mechanisms?

There is a heavily used object in HttpCache which was accessible through a property in a page-instance(Service.aspx). Now i wonder if it would be better to make it static because the HttpCache is shared across the application anyway.

The main reason i decided to make it static was because it is simpler to reference(`Service.dsRMA` vs. `((Service)Page).dsRMA`).

I'm aware of the problems that can occur regarding static functions and thread safety.

Thank you for your time.

**Before**:

C#

```
public ERPModel.dsRMA dsRMA {
    get {
        if (Cache("DS_RMA") == null) {
            Cache("DS_RMA") = new ERPModel.dsRMA();
        }
        return (ERPModel.dsRMA)Cache("DS_RMA");
    }
}
```

VB

```
Public ReadOnly Property dsRMA() As ERPModel.dsRMA
    Get
        If Cache("DS_RMA") Is Nothing Then
            Cache("DS_RMA") = New ERPModel.dsRMA
        End If
        Return DirectCast(Cache("DS_RMA"), ERPModel.dsRMA)
    End Get
End Property
```

**After**:

C#

```
public static ERPModel.dsRMA dsRMA {
    get {
        if (HttpContext.Current.Cache("DS_RMA") == null) {
            HttpContext.Current.Cache("DS_RMA") = new ERPModel.dsRMA();
        }
        return (ERPModel.dsRMA)HttpContext.Current.Cache("DS_RMA");
    }
}
```

VB

```
Public Shared ReadOnly Property dsRMA() As ERPModel.dsRMA
    Get
        If HttpContext.Current.Cache("DS_RMA") Is Nothing Then
            HttpContext.Current.Cache("DS_RMA") = New ERPModel.dsRMA
        End If
        Return DirectCast(HttpContext.Current.Cache("DS_RMA"), ERPModel.dsRMA)
    End Get
End Property
```

Comment: Hi Tim, I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're unlikely to notice any significant performance difference either way. (If anything, I would expect the static version to have a *slight* performance benefit. Benchmark to see what happens in your particular situation if the micro-optimisation is genuinely important.)

I would recommend doing whatever makes the most *semantic* sense in the context of your application domain: If the object logically belongs to a particular instance then use an instance property; if the object is shared between all instances then use a static property.

Answer (score 3):

If there isn't any threading or management issue, static methods are faster (not very faster), in fact instance methods are static methods with implicit `this` parameter.

**Edit**: by saying static methods and instance methods different is this, I didn't mean the way of calling, first one is managed in heap and second one in stack.

Comment: Virtual -1. This is wrong. calling static methods are different to instance method, first using CLR `call` the other using `callvirt`.

Comment: @Aliostad, may be you know better than Eric Lippert? I read blogs of eric lippert about how to implement virtual method patterns with just static methods ... simple google search helps you to find it.

Comment: I respect Eric Lippert a lot. And I do not need to google this, I know it. What you have written is correct but **implies** that static and instance methods are **called the same way**. That is not correct but the `this` pointer and being a little bit faster are both correct.

Comment: @Aliostad, I didn't said that they will be called in same way, but if you think so my apologize.

Comment: no need to apologise, just suggesting updating your answer to include a pointer on that. Cheers

Answer (score 2):

I have an article [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/biztalk/BizTalkCaching.aspx) which outlines various locking approaches. This was initially written for BizTalk but applies to general .NET.

I have explained **double `if` sandwitching the `lock` statement** which prevents `race conditions`. And that is the `TopCache` in the article. Just read the bottom third of the article.

---

### UPDATE

One word on static method performance. Static method is called by CLR `call` while instance methods are normally called by `callvirt`. `callvirt` which is a virtual call has to go up the inheritance hierarchy to find out which methods to call. This will cause some overhead but it is almost negligible. There are **exceptions** (for example explicit interface implementation) which is outside scope of this question.

From CLR via C#:

> The callvirt IL instruction can be
>   used to call instance and virtual
>   methods, not static methods. When the
>   callvirt instruction is used to call
>   an instance or virtual method, you
>   must specify a variable that refers to
>   an object. When the callvirt IL
>   instruction is used to call a
>   non-virtual instance method, the type
>   of the variable indicates which type
>   defines the method that the CLR should
>   call. When the callvirt IL instruction
>   is used to call a virtual instance
>   method, the CLR discovers the actual
>   type of the object being used to make
>   the call and then calls the method
>   polymorphically. It order to determine
>   the type, the variable being used to
>   make the call must not be null. In
>   other words, when compiling this call,
>   the JIT compiler generates code that
>   verifies that the variable's value is
>   not null. If it is null, the callvirt
>   instruction causes the CLR to throw a
>   NullReferenceException. This
>   additional check means that the
>   callvirt IL instruction executes
>   slightly more slowly than the call
>   instruction. Note that this null check
>   is performed even when the callvirt
>   instruction is used to call a
>   non-virtual instance method.

Answer (score 2):

Static methods are slightly faster than instance methods (See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/845657)). Instance methods have an additional null ref check before invoking the method on the target object.

But that said, this difference is neglible unless the call is in a hot spot (called frequently).