# Why compiler emits callvirt even for non-virtual methods?

Tags: c#, virtual-functions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is the C# compiler emitting a callvirt instruction for a GetType() method call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/845657/why-is-the-c-sharp-compiler-emitting-a-callvirt-instruction-for-a-gettype-meth)

I saw that when I call an instance method of a class the C# compiler emits the
 `callvirt` instruction to call that method, why is this so ?

Does it mean all instance methods are treated as `virtual methods` by the compiler, what's this mystery ?

Comment: `callvirt` has the nice property of performing a `null` check; note that in (some) cases where the compiler *knows* that a non-virtual call has a non-null receiver, it will issue a `call` instruction.

Answer (score 15):

Hans and Mike's answers are correct. Just to add a little bit of extra information:

- The `callvirt` instruction is explicitly documented as legal on a non-virtual method precisely so that you get the null check behaviour.
- In those rare cases where the C# compiler proves that a non-virtual call cannot possibly have a null receiver, it falls back to `call` and saves the nanosecond it takes to do the null check. For example, if you have `(new C()).InstanceMethod()` then that should be generated as `call`, not `callvirt` because the compiler knows that the receiving expression is never null. (If the allocation fails then an exception is thrown, so the call will never be performed.)

Comment: Is newobj+call the only instance where the C# compiler doesn't use callvirt?

Comment: @tinister: no. There are lots of expressions that are easily seen to be non null.

Comment: `+1` just so you can hit 200k :)

Comment: @MikeChristensen: Thanks! I was worried about that.

Comment: Shouldn't the jitter be able eliminate the null check in most of those cases?

Comment: @CodesInChaos: Sure, but jitter analysis takes time. Why make it do more work?

Answer (score 14):

It is there to implement a promise made in the C# language specification.  Which says that it is not legal to call an instance method of a class through a null reference.  This may sound like an obvious feature, but it is not actually that common in OOP languages.  In particular the C++/CLI compiler doesn't have it.  And the CLI spec doesn't have it.  An unmanaged language like C++ doesn't have it.

It even comes to a good end, sometimes, when the instance method doesn't use any non-static class members.  Such a method should of course be static but that is not required or enforced.

The C# requirement is very nice, it makes a `NullReferenceException` much easier to diagnose.  Since they are generated at the call site instead of inside the instance method., it clarifies that the object reference is null.  Figuring out that the *this* reference is null inside a method is kinda difficult, especially since you can't see it.  Further complicated by the address not actually being null, accessing a field of a class will generate an address that's offset from 0.  Which in turn is *unsafe* if the object is humongous, more than 64 kilobytes.  Accessing a field at the end of such a big object won't necessarily generate a processor exception, you'll just read random junk.  Or corrupt memory if you write it.

So the C# team looked for a cheap way to implement the null test.  And found one in the `callvirt` IL instruction.  Which, unlike `call`, *does* promise an exception in the CLI specification.  A very cheap test, it requires only a single machine code instruction.  And doesn't require a branch, that's very expensive if the processor's branch prediction logic guesses wrong.

You now also know why String.Equals() contains this bit of mysterious code:

```
public override bool Equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == null)
        throw new NullReferenceException();
    // etc...
}
```

Comment: http://ideone.com/lHukZ5 Here's the link for the C++ call on null.

Answer (score 2):

**Short answer:** It's safer that way.

`callvirt` will first check if the object is null, and throw an exception if so.

You'll notice that calling a static method will still use `call`, as the object cannot be null.

[Here's](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericgu/archive/2008/07/02/why-does-c-always-use-callvirt.aspx) a little history.