# Do non-virtual C# methods in a base class still incur vtable overheads?

Tags: c#, performance, static, instance, vtable

Considering C# written for maximum performance, there are two ways we can have base class methods (note: we're talking about a stateless class here, no fields, only methods):

- instance class A provides a base for inheritance / extension by class B - the usual pattern
- static class A with static methods (pure functions) called statically by "extender" class B

I like option A because it makes the relationship clearer. What I'm wondering is, if all these base class methods are non-virtual, i.e. in the base class A they already cannot be overridden, are there vtable calls? Obviously, "non-virtual" implies no, but if there are any overheads, I'd like to know.

Comment: `callvirt` is used either way.

Comment: @CodeCaster can you provide a reference?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/845657/why-is-the-c-sharp-compiler-emitting-a-callvirt-instruction-for-a-gettype-meth

Comment: It's just the way C# and the CLR work. Each type has a method table, whether those methods are virtual or not.

Comment: @CodeCaster Hmm, not according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/193939/call-and-callvirt). Thanks for the intro to `callvirt`, helps me to search.

Comment: Even non-virtual calls to an instance method are made with the exact equivalent of a virtual call.  Giving up a bit of perf for a very nice guarantee, a NullReferenceException is always raised at the call site.  Diagnosing NRE when *this* is null is quite ugly.  Only a call to a static method is non-virtual.  That includes extension methods btw.

Comment: @HansPassant Feel free to supply that as an answer to get the checkmark. Thank you.

Comment: Too many duplicates to decide which one is best.  CodeCaster's link is pretty decent, feel free to use it in your own dup vote.

Comment: It's clearly a very different form of question, but as you wish. I have my answer!

Comment: Also it might be interesting to see this talk https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7GTpwgsmHgU where Federico Lois shared their experience of eliminating virtual calls with Generics and structs for performance reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to @HansPassant (many thanks),

> Even non-virtual calls to an instance method are made with the exact
>   equivalent of a virtual call. Giving up a bit of perf for a very nice
>   guarantee, a NullReferenceException is always raised at the call site.
>   Diagnosing NRE when this is null is quite ugly.
>
> **Only a call to a static method is non-virtual**. That includes extension methods btw.

Comment: Hi, you need to distinguish and clarify here, whether you are referring to either `A.)` Non-virtual methods of a base class that has at least one other method that is virtual or `B.)` A concrete class that has 0 virtual methods and itself does not inherit from any classes or interfaces.

Answer (score 1):

**Update**

Search for "devirtualization" in this JIT section on improvements available starting as of .NET 6:
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/performance-improvements-in-net-6/#jit

See also
[Do sealed classes really offer performance benefits?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2134/do-sealed-classes-really-offer-performance-benefits/77152591#77152591)
and
https://stackoverflow.com/a/53785972/19497610