# call instead of callvirt in case of the new c# 6 "?" null check

Tags: c#, clr, roslyn, il, c#-6.0

Given the two methods:

```
    static void M1(Person p)
    {
        if (p != null)
        {
            var p1 = p.Name;
        }
    }

    static void M2(Person p)
    {
        var p1 = p?.Name;
    }
```

Why the M1 IL code use `callvirt`:

```
IL_0007:  brfalse.s  IL_0012
IL_0009:  nop
IL_000a:  ldarg.0
IL_000b:  callvirt   instance string ConsoleApplication4.Person::get_Name()
```

and the M2 IL use `call`:

```
brtrue.s   IL_0007
IL_0004:  ldnull
IL_0005:  br.s       IL_000d
IL_0007:  ldarg.0
IL_0008:  call       instance string ConsoleApplication4.Person::get_Name()
```

I just can guess that it because in M2 we know that `p` isn't null and its like

```
new MyClass().MyMethod();
```

Is it true?

If it is, what if `p` will be null in other thread?

Comment: It would be nice to show how an actual virtual member is called when overridden. Specifically in the presence of `?.`. What is the behavior when an overridden member is `sealed` and specifically invoked? If if it is still `callvirt`, it may be an optimization opportunity in Roslyn :)

Comment: @leppie C# generate `callvirt` for this. But I don't know what happening at runtime.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it's clearly now,

> This is an easy and thread-safe way to check for null before you trigger an event. The reason it’s thread-safe is that the feature evaluates the left-hand side only once, and keeps it in a temporary variable. [MSDN](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2014/11/20/new-features-in-c-6.aspx)

So it is safe to use `call` instruction here.

I wrote a [blog post](https://mycodingplace.wordpress.com/2014/04/22/call-vs-callvirt-instruction/) about the differences between `call` and `callvirt` and why C# generate `callvirt`

Thanks [Dan Lyons](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/7983/dan-lyons) for the MSDN link.

Answer (score 9):

The `callvirt` in M1 is [standard C# code generation](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericgu/archive/2008/07/02/why-does-c-always-use-callvirt.aspx).  It provides the language guarantee that an instance method can never be called with a null reference.  In other words, it ensures that `p != null` and generates NullReferenceException if it is null.  Your explicit test does not change that.

This guarantee is pretty nice, debugging NRE gets pretty hairy if it is `this` that is null.  Much easier to diagnose the mishap at the call-site instead, the debugger can quickly show you that it is `p` that is the troublemaker.

But of course `callvirt` is not for free, although the cost is very low, one extra processor instruction at runtime.  So if it *can* be substituted by `call` then the code will be faster by half a nanosecond, give or take.  It in fact can with the elvis operator since it already ensures that the reference isn't null so the C# 6 compiler took advantage of that and generates call instead of callvirt.

Comment: thanks for the details. I wrote about it a post in the link above but I didnt know the about the half a nanosecond:)

Answer (score 2):

Start with the fact that `callvirt` is used instead of `call` because of the C# rule that null objects may not have methods called on them, even when .NET allows it.

Now, in both your methods, we can show statically that `p` is not null, and as such using `call` instead of `callvirt` is not going to break this C# rule, and as such is a reasonable optimisation.

While `if (a != null) a.b` etc. is a common idiom, it takes analysis to realise that `a` cannot be null at the point that `b` is used. Adding that analysis to the compiler would take work specing, implementing, testing, and continually testing against regression bugs introduced by other changes.

`a?.b` is beyond an idiom, in that it's using an operator `?.` that C# must "know" about. So C# has to have the code to turn this into a null check followed by a member access. So the compiler has to know that at the point where the member access happens, `a` is not null. As such the logic to "know" the use of `call` is safe has already been done. It's no extra analysis work to realise that `call` can be used.

So the first case would require a bunch of extra work to use `call` and potentially introduce bugs, while the second case has to do that work anyway, so it might as well.