# C# Null propagation - Where does the magic happen?

Tags: c#, null, propagation

Null propagation is a very nice feature - but ***where*** and ***how*** does the actual magic happen?
Where does `frm?.Close()` get changed to `if(frm != null) frm.Close();` - Does it actually get changed to that kind of code at all?

Comment: In the compiler?

Comment: It's actually more close to `var temp = frm;if(temp != null) temp.Close();` such that it only evaluate only once. See [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operators#null-conditional-operators--and-)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It is done by the compiler. It doesn't change `frm?.Close()` to `if(frm != null) frm.Close();` in terms of re-writing the source code, but it *does* emit IL bytecode which checks for null.

Take the following example:

```
void Main()
{
    Person p = GetPerson();
    p?.DoIt();
}
```

Compiles to:

```
IL_0000:  ldarg.0     
IL_0001:  call        UserQuery.GetPerson
IL_0006:  dup         
IL_0007:  brtrue.s    IL_000B
IL_0009:  pop         
IL_000A:  ret         
IL_000B:  call        UserQuery+Person.DoIt
IL_0010:  ret
```

Which can be read as:

`call` - Call `GetPerson()` - store the result on the stack.
`dup` - Push the value onto the call stack (again)
`brtrue.s` - Pop the top value of the stack. If it is true, or not-null (reference type), then branch to `IL_000B`

If the result is false (that is, the object is *null*)
`pop` - Pops the stack (clear out the stack, we no longer need the value of `Person`)
`ret` - Returns

If the value is true (that is, the object is *not null*)
`call` - Call `DoIt()` on the top-most value of the stack (currently the result of `GetPerson`).
`ret`  - Returns

Manual null check:

```
Person p = GetPerson();
if (p != null)
    p.DoIt();

IL_0000:  ldarg.0     
IL_0001:  call        UserQuery.GetPerson
IL_0006:  stloc.0     // p
IL_0007:  ldloc.0     // p
IL_0008:  brfalse.s   IL_0010
IL_000A:  ldloc.0     // p
IL_000B:  callvirt    UserQuery+Person.DoIt
IL_0010:  ret
```

Note that the above is *not* the same as `?.`, however the effective outcome of the check is the same.

No null check:

```
void Main()
{
    Person p = GetPerson();
    p.DoIt();
}

IL_0000:  ldarg.0     
IL_0001:  call        UserQuery.GetPerson
IL_0006:  callvirt    UserQuery+Person.DoIt
IL_000B:  ret
```

Comment: Good answer but it would be nice if you also show the `if (p ! = null)` version and IL.

Comment: Interesting, obviously with manual check he null checks again at call http://stackoverflow.com/questions/193939/call-and-callvirt

Comment: Nicely explained... +10 I could see that you use the same LinqPad tool here.. :)

Comment: Since the Null propagation is not a Syntactical sugar like `Yield`, therefore it can only happen in `IL`, great explanation though.

Answer (score 2):

> Does it actually get changed to that kind of code at all?

Well, yes, but at the IL level, not the C# level.  The compiler emits IL code that roughly translates to the equivalent C# code you mention.