# Why Int32.ToString() emit call instruction instead of callvirt?

Tags: c#, .net, clr, cil, boxing

For the following code snippet:

```
struct Test
{
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "";
    }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Test a = new Test();
        a.ToString();
        Int32 b = 5;
        b.ToString();
    }
}
```

Compiler emits the following IL:

```
  .locals init ([0] valuetype ConsoleApplication2.Test a,
           [1] int32 b)
  IL_0000:  nop
  IL_0001:  ldloca.s   a
  IL_0003:  initobj    ConsoleApplication2.Test
  IL_0009:  ldloca.s   a
  IL_000b:  constrained. ConsoleApplication2.Test
  IL_0011:  callvirt   instance string [mscorlib]System.Object::ToString()
  IL_0016:  pop
  IL_0017:  ldc.i4.5
  IL_0018:  stloc.1
  IL_0019:  ldloca.s   b
  IL_001b:  call       instance string [mscorlib]System.Int32::ToString()
  IL_0020:  pop
  IL_0021:  ret
```

Since both value type `Test` and `Int32` override the `ToString()` method, I think no boxing will occur in both `a.ToString()` and `b.ToString()`. Thus I wonder why compiler emits `constraned`+`callvirt` for `Test`, and `call` for `Int32`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is an optimization done by the compiler for primitive types.

But even for custom structs, `callvirt` will actually be executed as `call` at runtime due to the `constrained.` opcode - in the case where the method was overridden. It allows the compiler to emit the same instructions in either case and let the runtime handle it.

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.constrained(v=vs.110).aspx):

> If `thisType` is a value type and `thisType` implements `method` then `ptr` is passed unmodified as the `this` pointer to a **`call` method instruction**, for the implementation of method by `thisType`.

And:

> The `constrained` opcode allows IL compilers to make a call to a virtual function in a uniform way **independent of whether `ptr` is a value type or a reference type**. Although it is intended for the case where `thisType` is a generic type variable, the constrained prefix also works for nongeneric types and can reduce the complexity of generating virtual calls in languages that hide the distinction between value types and reference types.

I don't know of any official documentation for the optimization, but you can see the remarks in the Roslyn repo for the [`MayUseCallForStructMethod` method](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/3ada6f06b1ceeec853259525a4d13e512ebf6e04/src/Compilers/CSharp/Portable/CodeGen/EmitExpression.cs#L1633).

As to why this optimization is deferred to the runtime for non-primitive types, I believe it's because the implementation can change. Imagine referencing a library that originally had an override for `ToString`, then changing the DLL (without recompiling!) to one where the override is removed. This would've caused a runtime exception. For primitives they can be sure it won't happen.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I also guess it is the compiler optimization working. But I cannot find any material supporting my guess. So I would appreciate it if you could provide any docs about this special optimization for primitive types. Thanks again.

Comment: Thank you @Eli Arbel , you really solved my question : )

Answer (score 0):

It is because `Int` is a framework provided sealed type and it will never happen that some other type overrides int `ToString` method, so compiler knows that it always needs to call the `ToString()` method implementation provided in the `int` type, so it does not need to use `callvirt` to figure out which implementation to call.

For primitve types compiler knows which implementation of `ToString` is to be called, but when we create a custom value type, it is a new one it never existed before, so compiler don't know about it and it needs to figure out about the implementation which one to call and where it resides, as it inherits by default from `Object`, so compiler has to do `callvirt` to locate the `ToString()` implementation provided for custom type if not overriden it will call the Object type which is obvious.

The following existing SO posts can help you in understanding this:

[Call and Callvirt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/193939/call-and-callvirt)

Comment: But all value types are implicitly sealed, so I think from this point of view, `Int32` and `Test` should behave in the same way. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: yes it is framework provided sealed type, that is special case

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what your "special case" means here. Would you please give me more details?

Comment: as @ali said compiler do optimization for performance of code execution as it can for primitive types which cannot be extended

Comment: makes sense, for custom types it happens on runtime, and for primitive types on compile time, right  @EliArbel ?

Comment: Hi @EliArbel, since custom value type is known to be sealed at compile time. I am curious why should the optimization be delayed to runtime, instead of compile time? Thanks a lot!

Comment: @LifuHuang it is decided on runtime which implementation of ToString to be called in custom value type, as there are 2 possibilities, you overrided ToString, or you did'nt, so it needs to figure out on run time, what i think

Comment: "compiler don't know about it" The compiler certainly has all the information to figure out that the override exists and it could use `call`. It just does decides not to, for the reason explained at the end of @EliArbel's answer.