# Why is the Enumerable.Any(Func<TSource, bool> predicate) slow compared to a foreach with an if statement when searching a List<T>

Tags: c#, linq, .net-6.0

Something has piqued my curiosity recently..

**Why** is the `Enumerable.Any(Func<TSource, bool> predicate)` method **so much slower** than manual foreach, **when they do the same thing?**

I've been messing with some benchmarks and thought of this. I'm checking of a `List<int>` contains and item that's approximately in the half of the list.

Here are my test results for a few diffent sizes of the list:

Items: 1 000, searched item: 543

| Method | Mean | Ratio | Allocated | Alloc Ratio |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Foreach | 838.3 ns | 1.00 | - | NA |
| Any | 3,348.8 ns | 4.05 | 40 B | NA |

Items: 10 000, searched item: 5 432

| Method | Mean | Ratio | Allocated | Alloc Ratio |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Foreach | 7.988 us | 1.00 | - | NA |
| Any | 30.991 us | 3.88 | 40 B | NA |

Items: 100 000, searched item: 54 321

| Method | Mean | Ratio | Allocated | Alloc Ratio |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Foreach | 82.35 us | 1.00 | - | NA |
| Any | 328.86 us | 4.00 | 40 B | NA |

There are two benchmarks:

- **Foreach**: manual `foreach` with an `if` statement
- **Any**: LINQ's `Any` method (that turns into `Enumerable.Any`)

Here's my code for the benchmarks (using BenchmarkDotNet, .NET 6.0 console app running in Release mode):

```cs
[MemoryDiagnoser(displayGenColumns: false)]
[HideColumns("Error", "StdDev", "RatioSD")]
public class Benchmarks
{
    private readonly List<int> _items;
    private readonly Func<int, bool> _filter;

    public Benchmarks()
    {
        _items = Enumerable.Range(1, 10_000).ToList();
        _filter = x => x == 5432;
    }

    [Benchmark(Baseline = true)]
    public bool Foreach()
    {
        if (_items is null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(_items));
        }

        if (_filter is null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(_filter));
        }

        foreach (var item in _items)
        {
            if (_filter(item))
            {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public bool Any()
    {
        return _items.Any(_filter);
    }
}
```

The **Any** approach is **4 times slower** and allocates a bit of memory despite my best attempts to optimize it.

I tried to make the **Any** approach faster by caching the predicate (`Func<int, bool>`) in a variable (`_filter`). However, it still allocates 40B and I have no idea why...

When decompiled, the **Any** approach turns into `Enumerable.Any(Func<TSource, bool> predicate)` method:

```cs
public static bool Any<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, bool> predicate)
{
    if (source == null)
    {
        ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentNullException(ExceptionArgument.source);
    }

    if (predicate == null)
    {
        ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentNullException(ExceptionArgument.predicate);
    }

    foreach (TSource element in source)
    {
        if (predicate(element))
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

How is the **Any** approach different from the **Foreach** approach? Just curious...

Comment: *"Something has peaked my curiosity recently"*. That your curiosity is at maximum has piqued my curiosity. ;-)

Comment: One thing I'd try to make the comparisons fairer is declaring `_items` as `IEnumerable<int>` instead of `List<int>`. Your `foreach` loop "knows" that it's iterating over a `List<T>`, so it's able to use the `List<T>.Enumerator` struct. I'd be surprised if that made that much difference, but it's the first thing I'd try.

Comment: Thanks @JonSkeet! that was the key difference. When changed to `IEnumerable<int>` the two approaches perform the same.

Comment: Well, I would have expected Any to test for IList or ICollection and use them if possible. Linq does that in many places

Comment: To make it clearer all the findings in the edit should be their own answer instead of editing them into the question like this.

Comment: @cafce25 I separated my findings into an answer, thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Jon Skeet suggested in the comments, I tried changing the `_items` collection from a `List<int>` to `IEnumerable<int>` to make the comparison fair. In short, that seems to be the key difference. My **Foreach** seems to be taking advantage of that fact that it know the `_items` collection is a `List<T>` while the `Enumerable.Any` method takes an `IEnumerable<int>`.

Here are the benchmark results for that:

Items: 1 000, searched item: 543

| Method | Mean | Ratio | Allocated | Alloc Ratio |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Foreach | 2.126 us | 1.00 | 40 B | 1.00 |
| Any | 2.131 us | 1.00 | 40 B | 1.00 |

Items: 10 000, searched item: 5 432

| Method | Mean | Ratio | Allocated | Alloc Ratio |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Foreach | 21.35 us | 1.00 | 40 B | 1.00 |
| Any | 21.20 us | 0.99 | 40 B | 1.00 |

Items: 100 000, searched item: 54 321

| Method | Mean | Ratio | Allocated | Alloc Ratio |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Foreach | 220.7 us | 1.00 | 40 B | 1.00 |
| Any | 219.1 us | 0.99 | 40 B | 1.00 |

When working with `IEnumerable<int>`, the two approaches are performing the same. Thanks Jon Skeet!

Answer (score 8):

Compiler can optimize working with the `List<T>` inside foreach (compared to `IEnumerable<T>`). I would not be able to explain in the details, but if you check the generated IL (for example at [sharplab.io](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LglgNgPgAgTARgLACgYAYAEMEBYDcqMAzNnJgMKYDeqm92pMumAsgBQAyYAzsADxgAdsAB8mAB4BKGnQbyAZgHsATgFMAhgGMAFuwBuGlZjAmhkqbRTybDHAE52YKYWu3MAXzn0vb+t8ZsFlYEdmwEYkERcQBPGSt3TADFVU1dAyMTM0w4hMS7BEdnV0TfeV8PIA==)) you already will see the differences - compiler can call concrete methods on [`List<T>.Enumerator`](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Collections/Generic/List.cs,1147) instead polymorphic invocation via `callvirt` ([Call and Callvirt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/193939/call-and-callvirt)). Not sure that this (and one time allocation due to working with `struct List<T>.Enumerator` via interface) results in such performance difference. Possibly runtime can optimize it even more (check out the JIT Asm difference at [sharplab.io](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LglgNgPgAgTARgLACgYAYAEMEBYDcqMAzNnJgMKYDeqm92pMumAsgBQAyYAzsADxgAdsAB8mAB4BKGnQbyAZgHsATgFMAhgGMAFuwBuGlZjAmhkqbRTybDHAE52YKYWu3MAXzn0vb+t8ZsFlYEdmwEYkERcQBPGSt3TADFVU1dAyMTM0w4hMS7BEdnV0TfeV8PIA==) if you want to try going deeper).

If you check the source code for [`Enumerable.Any`](https://source.dot.net/#System.Linq/System/Linq/AnyAll.cs,23) you will see that it uses the same `foreach` loop and difference boils down to using `IEnumerable` interface:

```cs
public static bool Any<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, bool> predicate)
{
    if (source == null)
    {
        ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentNullException(ExceptionArgument.source);
    }
 
    if (predicate == null)
    {
        ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentNullException(ExceptionArgument.predicate);
    }
 
    foreach (TSource element in source)
    {
        if (predicate(element))
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
 
    return false;
}
```

So, as correctly diagnosed by [@Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet) in the comments, the difference comes from using list vs enumerable.

Comment: Why after inlining (and I hope the JIT inlines those methods) it cannot recognize that we're calling a concrete method?