# Why is the System class declared as "final" in Java?

Tags: java, class, system, final

As per my understanding, a class is declared as final to prevent it from being extended/inherited. So I see there can be security and probably some performance gains in this regard.

But is there a very specific design decision behind this? Say for eg: to realize some kind of design pattern? I did go around a similar thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30258274/why-system-class-declared-as-final-and-with-private-constructor)!  but the answer was not really what I was looking for

Comment: Still the linked question discusses the problem quite well. See also [my comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30258274/why-system-class-declared-as-final-and-with-private-constructor#comment48616517_30258274) there. Actually I don't see what could be added, thus I'd vote to close this as duplicate.

Comment: I don't know why the answer doesn't fit your expectations but this is the only valid answer I know related to your question.

Answer (score 1):

Singleton Pattern:

-Private Constructor

-Only static methods

-No need to have more than one object of this class or an object at all

-No need to extend this fundamental class

Comment: That's not a Singleton pattern. `Runtime.getRuntime()` is a singleton, but `System` is utility class.

Comment: than for arguments sake lets call it the Java System Class Pattern....Singleton is the closest PAttern. The Class itself is instantiated/loaded by the JVM to use the static fields and functions

Comment: it is not singleton pattern because in singleton pattern the object is not final

Comment: what? The class itself is final and why shouldnt the object of a Singleton not be final also? You just need one of them and you dont instantiate it more than once while code is running...