# Why does AutoFixture.AutoMoq make recursive mocks by default?

Tags: c#, mocking, moq, autofixture

Moq does not make recursive mocks by default. That is, for members without expectations on a mock, Moq returns default values. For example, given:

```
public interface IFoo
{
    Bar Bar();
}
```

and

```
public class Bar
{
}
```

then:

```
[TestMethod]
public void RecursiveMocksAreDisabledByDefaultInMoq()
{
    var foo = new Mock<IFoo>().Object;
    Assert.IsNull(foo.Bar());
}
```

However, in AutoFixture.AutoMoq, recursive mocks are enabled by default, as in:

```
[TestMethod]
public void RecursiveMocksAreEnabledByDefaultInAutoFixture()
{
    var fixture = new Fixture().Customize(new AutoMoqCustomization());
    var foo = fixture.Create<IFoo>();
    Assert.IsNotNull(foo.Bar());
}
```

Why is that? And, how to turn off automatic recursive mocks in AutoFixture.AutoMoq?

Thanks

```
Moq.3.1.416.3
AutoFixture.AutoMoq.3.16.5
```

Comment: You might find elements of [this discussion pertaining to the default return value in AutoFoq](https://foq.codeplex.com/discussions/470568) useful - AutoFoq doesn't OOTB change Foq behaviour (resulting in `null` return values from methods OOTB). I also strongly recommend AutoFoq and Foq - however I appreciate changing mocking libs isnt something you 'just do'. I personally for the longest time didnt understand how a mocking library could be so significantly more usable than Moq and discounted it for a long time despite being aware of it. (NB I write most of my tests in F#)

Comment: Because "AutoFixture is an opinionated library, and one of the opinions it holds is that nulls are invalid return values." http://stackoverflow.com/a/18170070/126014

Comment: See also https://autofixture.codeplex.com/workitem/4261

Comment: @MarkSeemann am aware of the cited post. AutoFoq defaults to returning nulls. AutoMoq returns recursive Mocks. There is an inconsistency. That's my main point. As you know I have no problem with Opinionated design (esp when you explain things which you normally do fantastically) and love, appreciate and use Auto* very much on a daily basis

Comment: Yes... Until [the next major release](https://github.com/AutoFixture/AutoFixture/issues/214), where AutoFoq will use [Foq's new return strategy](https://foq.codeplex.com/discussions/470568), it currently uses Foq's  1.x behaviour (returning `null` for properties and methods that have not been explicitly setup).

Comment: @NikosBaxevanis Ah, cool. Wasnt aware that had been agreed (or if I was I forgot :). I personally am happy with things falling that way. Beluchin: I hope you agree this makes sense.

Comment: @MarkSeemann Very sorry, for some reason I skipped over you stating that the opinion was that `null`s are invalid return values and hence replied as if you hadn't made that clear. Changing the AutoFoq strategy to have Foq also source values for non-mocks from AF closes that loop excellently. (Now I just have to hope you start dogfooding AutoFoq and run into [a clash between it's and your meanings of `verify`](https://twitter.com/rbartelink/status/433346161223557120) :P)

Comment: I am ok with the approach of returning recursive mocks by default. It would be nice, though, to have an easy way to disable it.

Answer (score 3):

The comments to the question ought to answer the original question of *why*, but then there's the follow-up comment:

> It would be nice, though, to have an easy way to disable [recursive mocks].

It's not *that* hard to do. If you look at the implementation of `AutoMoqCustomization`, it's the [use of `MockPostProcessor`](https://github.com/AutoFixture/AutoFixture/blob/5320b403949f6e7b0b0c3881f4cc57d288f85aa4/Src/AutoMoq/AutoMoqCustomization.cs#L58) that turns on recursive mocks. If you don't want that, you can create your own Customization that doesn't do that:

```
public class AutoNonRecursiveMoqCustomization : ICustomization
{
    public void Customize(IFixture fixture)
    {
        if (fixture == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("fixture");

        fixture.Customizations.Add(
            new MethodInvoker(
                new MockConstructorQuery()));
        fixture.ResidueCollectors.Add(new MockRelay());
    }
}
```

`MockPostprocessor` also sets `CallBase` to `true`, so by omitting `MockPostprocessor` you also disable that `CallBase` setting.