# How to Customize AutoFixture to Return Null Sometimes

Tags: c#, unit-testing, autofixture

In this sample code, I want to configure a `Fixture` object to return `null` for strings half of the time.

```
void Test()
{
    var fixture = new Fixture();

    fixture.Customize<string>(x => x.FromFactory(CreateString));

    var str1 = fixture.Create<string>();

    //error occurs here when string should come back null
    var str2 = fixture.Create<string>(); 
}

bool _createString = false;

string CreateString()
{
    _createString = !_createString;

    return _createString ? "test" : null;
}
```

The problem is, whenever my factory returns `null`, I get an `InvalidOperationException`:

> The specimen returned by the decorated ISpecimenBuilder is not compatible with System.String.

This happens for any type where I return `null` inside a factory. Is there any way to configure `AutoFixture` to return `null` for a requested object?

Comment: Internally AutoFixture use Guid as a value for generating random string. I will just do this line of code `return _createString ? "test" : Guid.Empty.ToString();`

Comment: @CodeNotFound `String` was just an example, and I want a null string, not an empty string, or an empty guid. I want to return null for several types of objects, as it's a very valid test case in many test scenarios.

Comment: AutoFixture is an opinionated library, and one of the opinions it holds is that [nulls are invalid return values](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18170070/467754).

Comment: This looks like a bug. Will investigate further...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This was a defect. It ought to be addressed in [AutoFixture 3.36.11](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AutoFixture/3.36.11).

Comment: Fix confirmed. It works now.  Thanks for the quick turnaround!